Edit plotly labels by double click
I'm working on a PyQt app that uses Plotly to create some figures. I use QWebEngineView to display the HTML in a Python window by doing something like this:
    return f"""
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
        </head>
        <body style='margin:0; padding:0; background-color:{self.figure_bg_color};'>
            {plot_div}
        </body>
    </html>
    """

In my figures, the label, ylabel, and title are set automatically.
I was wondering if there is a way to let the user double-click on them so it will become editable and they could change the text, or if I have to create some widget to do it.

it is in HTML so it may need to write code in JavaScript, not in Python.

plotly forum: Double click event - Plotly Fundamentals - Plotly Community Forum

from what i understand it seems to work only inside the figure area, not where the labels are.

plotly uses JavaScript so it may need to use DevTools in FIrefox/Chrome to see how it works in browser and use own code in JavaScript to run code when you click some object. And it may need to use HTML to display place for editing - ie. <input>. So it needs more work.
